# Directional functionality of a compass near large metallic objects

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields

Can a large, nearby metallic object such as a bridge significantly affect the directional functionality of a compass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it can as can ferromagnetic objects below the ground and it does not have to be particularly large.

Image **1** is a compass without any ferromagnetic objects around.

[image]

Image **2** shows an increase clockwise deflection due to the presence of a steel file.

Image **3** shows a decreased clockwise deflection due to the presence of a steel file which I had moved compared with its position in image **2** which has over time been magnetized by being in the Earth's magnetic field (or possibly being close to a magnet at some time).

I tested a steel paper clip and that showed a very small increase in the clockwise deflection wherever I placed the paper clip to the right (or left to show it was unmagnetised) of the compass.
I found that most of my steel tools were magnetized to some degree.

As a precaution, when students plot magnetic field lines around a magnet using a plotting compass they should check under the bench to make sure they are not doing their experiment close to steel gas pipes and/or steel conduit.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I was a passenger in a moving vehicle a few days ago on a meandering road, expecting to see a more or less south or southwest direction on my compass, but it showed west, when I noticed a big bridge nearby, which initiated my curiosity. There also seems to be a lag of about 1 second until the compass arrow repositions itself when switching one's orientation, even when standing in a stationary position.